# Android Toolbar Navigation icon doesnt change back to "3 lines" icon when returning to main screen

Tags: android, toolbar

I have an app consisting of an activity with two fragment areas - on the top a toolbar fragment, and below that a "content" fragment area that contains whatever fragment I want to load. As the user progresses through the app the content area is populated by different single fragments to reflect this (only one fragment at a time, taking up the whole area that isnt taken up by the toolbar fragment), but the toolbar fragment stays the same. So far so good.. but when the user is on the first screen, before he has navigated to a different fragment, the navigation icon (top left) on the toolbar shows the 3-line icon indicating the user is on the top level of the app. When the user changes to a different content fragment this navigation icon turns into an arrow pointing back, and clicking on it performs onbackpressed() on the content fragment (going one backwards in the backstack) *but* the navigation icon stays as a back arrow - it doesnt turn back to the 3-line icon. How can I restore it back to the 3 line icon every time the user gets back to the first fragment in the content area?

Here is my code:

Inside the toolbar fragment:

```
    ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Inside the main activity that holds all the fragments:

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    onBackPressed();

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by putting the following into onoptionsitemselected:

```
     @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    onBackPressed();

    Fragment testFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FIRST_FRAGMENT);

    if (testFragment.isVisible()) {
        setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    }

    return true;
}
```